# WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "kvssink"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, gstreamer, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying Kinesis Video Stream via https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/gs-send-data.html
I have already installled it

> Success in building the Kinesis Video Streams Producer SDK !!!
>   Now you can set the environment variables before running the sample applications
>   by running source set_kvs_sdk_env.sh
>   Also, you may want to add the following environment variables to set it permanently
>   in /home/huynv/.bashrc or /home/huynv/.bash_profile or /home/huynv/.zshrc
>   Success in building kinesis-video-gstreamer-plugin !!!

but when get that warning when run:

> $ gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src do-timestamp=TRUE device=/dev/video0 ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc,alignment=au ! kvssink stream-name="MyKinesisVideoStream" storage-size=512 access-key="YourAccessKey" secret-key="YourSecretKey" aws-region="YourAWSRegion"

it's show

> WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "kvssink"

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, python3

Somebody help me, please!

Comment: If plugin is built properly, find where it is built. Then export GST_PLUGIN_PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to that path.

Comment: Hi @MayurK. Thanks for comment. It's worked. But i have a next problem. When I run the command. It's show:
(gst-plugin-scanner:10781): GStreamer-WARNING **: Failed to load plugin '/home/huynv/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmxf.so': /home/huynv/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib/libgstbase-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: gst_make_element_message_details

Can you help me!

Comment: Looks like "libgstmxf.so" is in some other path. You need to export all paths to the above said macros.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, it was because I used the `min_install_script`, and I think the plugin only gets built if you use the full install script.

Try this:

cd to your `kinesis-video-native-build` directory and execute the commands below

(change the directory in the commands below to your directory for the sdk):

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/opt/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib:$GST_PLUGIN_PATH
sudo ./gstreamer-plugin-install-script
```

Comment: In addition to setting the paths, I also had to copy libgstkvssink.so to `<sdk-home>/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib/` to get this to work.

Answer (score -1):

I did the above steps for raspberry pi ie. 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export GST_PLUGIN_PATH=/kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib:$GST_PLUGIN_PATH

and also copied all the .so files from the

libcproducer.so  libgstkvssink.so    libproducer.so to the kinesis-video-native-build/downloads/local/lib folder